# I am getting an error in my code from an sql statement that works fine in the query design in MS Access

Tags: sql, arrays, ms-access

The SQL statement runs properly in the query design in MS Access but I get the following error in the netbeans code:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 4.

I don't know what this error message means by too few parameters so I do not know how to fix it.

Any help on why my code is not working will be grateful.

This class imports two tables from a database as one SQL statement into two arrays.

```
public class GuestArray
{
private Guest[] guest = new Guest[100];
private Reservations[] res = new Reservations[100];
private int size =0;
Connect conn = new Connect("GuestInfo.mdb");
public GuestArray()
{
    String sql = "SELECT GuestID, Title,Name,Surname,CountryLivingIn,"
    + "contactNumber,emailAddress,Day(checkInDate)AS idd, MONTH(checkInDate) AS imm,"
    + " YEAR(checkInDate) AS iYY, Day(checkOutDate)AS odd, MONTH(checkOutDate) AS omm, "
    + "YEAR(checkOutDate) AS oYY,RoomType,Adults,Children,Requests FROM ReservationDetails,"
    + "GuestDetails WHERE GuestDetails.GuestID=ReservationDetails.ReservationID";
    try
    {
        ResultSet rs = conn.query(sql);

        while(rs.next())
        {
            int id = rs.getInt("GuestID");
            String t = rs.getString("Title");
            String n = rs.getString("Name");
            String s = rs.getString("Surname");
            String c = rs.getString("CountryLivingIn");
            String num = rs.getString("contactNumber");
            String e = rs.getString("emailAddress");

            guest[size] = new Guest(id,t,n,s,c,num,e);

            int cid = rs.getInt("idd");//check-in-day
            int cim = rs.getInt("imm");//check-in-month
            int ciy = rs.getInt("iyy");//check-in-year
            int cod = rs.getInt("odd");//check-out-day
            int com = rs.getInt("omm");//check-out-month
            int coy = rs.getInt("oyy");//check-out-year
            String rt = rs.getString("RoomType");
            int ad = rs.getInt("Adults");
            int ch = rs.getInt("Children");
            String req = rs.getString("Requests");

            res[size] = new Reservations(id,t,n,s,c,num,e,cid,cim,ciy,cod,com,coy,rt,ad,ch,req);
            size++;                
        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe there is a non existent column (mistyped ?) in your query... see [this post.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216425 "this")

Comment: Can you post the top of the stack trace (with line number) for that exception and identify the associated line number in your code?

Comment: This error occurs when you have typed in a field name, which doesn't exist OR is misspelled in the SQL. At 1st glance, I can see you use `ID` as well as `GuestID` in the SQL.

Comment: I changed GuestDetails.ID which should be GuestID but i still get the error:  java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 5.

Comment: There might be another misspelled column name... you are almost there!

Comment: Did you change it to GuestDetails.GuestID ?

Comment: i checked my sql statement in the query design in Microsoft Database and it works properly but i keep getting this error. If it works in the query design then can i assume all my columns are spelled correctly

Comment: "Microsoft Database" is not an actual product. There is "SQL Server", one of it's derivatives ("SQL Server CE" or "Express"), or "MS Access", which is a desktop database. There is no generic "Microsoft Database". Please be specific in both your question and your tags; it helps get you an answer sooner. :-)

Comment: Is the exception being thrown at the Connect line or con.query line?

Comment: Simplify your query. Comment out rs.getX lines (you don't need them until your query works) simplify the SELECT part of your query so it has only GuestId and start adding one field at a time. There's a chance that the JDBC adapter doesn't quite process the sql in the same way the desktop app does - adding one field at a time may help you identify the cause.

Comment: `Name` is a reserved word in Access, try enclosing it in square brackets: `SELECT GuestID, Title,[Name],`